# Common types for all subprojects

Tags: typescript

How can I add common types for all my subprojects?
E.g. all my projects are using shaders (glsl), so I don't want to declare them every time.
When I keep the d.ts files in the root directory it doesn't work.

My structure:

```
-packages
  --common
  --project-first
    --tsconfig.json (extending tsconfig in the main folder)
-typings
  --glsl.d.ts (here it doesn't work, I have to move this file to each project (/packages/project-first for example)
-tsconfig.json
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this, I am facing the same problem ???